# Vote to Close Migrations

Tags: support, close-reasons

When voting to close I only see a single migration path as shown below:
[image]

Shouldn't this include the Big 4 plus meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is correct -- we don't allow migrations until a site is fully public beta.

Also, the migration paths have to be proven based on existing evidence of closed questions.

Diamond mods can do arbitrary site to site migrations, but this should only be used in exceptional circumstances.